# svn checkout is not working with build.xml

Tags: svn

I want to checkout my code from (tortoise) svn folder to some other working directory.

Build.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="svn-test" basedir="." default="checkoutThis">
<property file="build.properties" />
<path id="project.classpath">
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\jsvn-0.9-dev.jar" />
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\commons-lang-2.3.jar" />
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\jakarta-regexp-1.3.jar" />
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnant.jar"/>
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnkit.jar"/>
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnjavahl.jar"/>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpath="C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnant.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnClientAdapter.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnkit.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-ant\ant-1.8.2\lib\svnjavahl.jar" />
<target name="checkoutThis">

<svn username="sss" password="sss">
<checkout url="https://svn.strobilanthes.com/svn/nutanstplus/" revision="HEAD" destPath="Sample_SVN" />
</svn>
</target>
<target name="build" depends="checkoutThis">
<description>Main target</description>
</target>
</project>
```

when run the build.xml it showing :

```
E:\ant-for-example>ant

Buildfile: E:\ant-for-example\build.xml

checkoutThis:
      [svn] <Checkout> started ...
```

But it does not copy the files in to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this before "taskdef"

```
  <taskdef name="svn" classname="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask" classpathref="project.classpath"/>
```